# passing string from c++ to c# using delegates

Tags: c#, mfc, interop, clr, marshalling

I inherited a partially implemented application and am unsure if it is at all heading in the right direction. The main application is written using MFC. When the c# portion of the application is launched it uses a c# dll that results in a winform control embedded in a mfc dialog.

The issue I am not able to figure out is how to get a string from the c++ side to the c# code. I have tried all MarshalAs(...) options based on error message associated with this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ET53.png)

```
//c#

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] 
        public delegate string GetUnitStringFunc(int unitEnum);
        GetUnitStringFunc CallInteropGetUnitString;
        public void SetGetUnitString(IntPtr f)
        {
            CallInteropGetUnitString = (GetUnitStringFunc)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(f, typeof(GetUnitStringFunc));
        }

        public string GetUnitString(int unitEnum)
        {
            string str = CallInteropGetUnitString(unitEnum); //This line fails after executing c++ code.
            return str;
        }
```

```
//C++
void CFormView::InitializeInterop()
{
    //...
    interop = m_ViewControl->presenter->interop;
    interop->SetGetEnumFromStr(System::IntPtr(CFormView::GetEnumFromStr));
    interop->SetGetUnitString(System::IntPtr(CFormView::GetStrForEnum));
}

//This works fine
int CFormView::GetEnumFromStr(LPCSTR unitStr)
{
     int val = 0;
     //some checking unitStr in order to set val
     //...
     //...
     return val
}

//can not get this to work
string CFormView::GetStrForEnum()
{
    // When returning System::string^ instead I get a redefinition error
    // When returing LPCSTR I get an error on the c++ side with no information
    return "Some String from c++";
}
```

To add to this, there has to be a much cleaner way to do this. I just have not been able to find anything that seems to fit my situation.

Comment: A C++ object cannot possibly cross an ABI boundary. If you need string values to travel across an unmanaged/managed boundary, either pass a pointer and size, or use a string type that follows a documented ABI (such as `BSTR`).

Comment: I use `CComBSTR` indeed. I agree with @IInspectable.

Comment: @IInspectable I am a bit confused on how I can return two parameters. Is there a way to do an equivalent c# out and c++ pointer as function parameters that I have not seen? I will look into CComBstr and BSTR.

Comment: You will only need to pass the length explicitly in the general case (i.e. a character string that isn't terminated by a dedicated character). Standard C-style strings can be passed as a pointer alone, where the length is implied by the first NUL character. Though if you need to transfer ownership, a C-style string won't do. You would have to use a `BSTR`. The system knows how to read, modify, and delete the controlled sequence, regardless of who allocated the string.

Comment: @IInspectable sorry but can you provide some code... I am super new to this. 

With what I have I am a bit worried about memory leaks but I have something like this: 

c++ side:
HRESULT CFormView::GetString(BSTR* pRsp) 
{ 
    *pRsp = ::SysAllocatStringLen(L"String", 6)
    return S_OK;
}
 and I am only getting "S" on the c# function 
string GetString(int enum) 
{ 
    string response = ""; 
    CallInteropGetString(out response); 
    return respose; 
}

I am getting a generic exception thrown when returning to the c# code followed by corrupted heap exception. Thanks again

Comment: @IInspectable I would want to just inform the c# what an equivalent string is for the passed int(enum) value. I would not think there should be any retention of the data. just want to send it to the c# side so it can capture the data to display to the user... There was supposed to be link breaks in the last comment there but it looks like stack overflow removes them???

Comment: I used to do this stuff. I used COM. Put the C# WinForm in a different DLL. Make it driveable via COM. Let COM handle the Marshaling from C++ to COM.